# CommanderJS I can't get value from option

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-commander

I wrote a cli program in nodejs, using commanderjs tool but when I tried, it can't get value from process.argv. please help this out.

```js
//cli.js
const program = require('commander');

program
     .version("0.0.1")
     .option("-a, --add", "add something")
     .option("-u, --update", "update something")
     .option("-r, --remove", "remove something")
    .parse(process.argv);

console.log(`version ${program.version} You Choose: `);

if (program.add) {
    console.log("  add something")
}
if (program.update) {
    console.log("  update something")
}
if (program.remove) {
    console.log("  remove something")
}
```

I run

```
$ node cli.js --add
version version(str, flags, description) {
    if (str === undefined) return this._version;
    this._version = str;
    flags = flags || '-V, --version';
    description = description || 'output the version number';
    const versionOption = this.createOption(flags, description);
    this._versionOptionName = versionOption.attributeName();
    this.options.push(versionOption);
    this.on('option:' + versionOption.name(), () => {
      this._outputConfiguration.writeOut(`${str}\n`);
      this._exit(0, 'commander.version', str);
    });
    return this;
  } You Choose:
```

can't get value, why is that?

Comment: The way the option values are stored changed in Commander v7. You may have been following an older example. @gvmani answer shows the correct way to access them.

Comment: program.version is a function which displays the version when requested on the command line with -V or --version. It is not the string you passed into the version() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the opts function to access the parsed arguments. The version will be automnatically displayed with -V flag.

```
const program = require('commander');

program
     .version("0.0.1")
     .option("-a, --add", "add something")
     .option("-u, --update", "update something")
     .option("-r, --remove", "remove something")
    .parse(process.argv);
let options = program.opts();


if (options.add) {
    console.log("  add something")
}
if (options.update) {
    console.log("  update something")
}
if (options.remove) {
    console.log("  remove something")
}
```